# Textbox (and other controls) - "Object not set to an instance...."

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, wcf

I realize this is a common error and I've followed the many fixes to this problem offered online but have yet to find a solution.

I developed a winform app which gets JSON from an external website.  I click a button control and the app goes through my json serialiser method and posts the results to a textbox and appends to a textarea.

```
 public void RenderData(string buttonText)
    {

        if (buttonText == "Start")
        {
            EquationData deserializedData = getData("http://test.ethorstat.com/test.ashx");

            var processed = new ProcessEquation();
            int result = processed.Calculate(deserializedData);

            string res = deserializedData.parm1 + "  " + deserializedData.op + "  " + deserializedData.parm2 +
                " = " + result;
            TextBoxResult.Text = res;

            equation.Append("  " + deserializedData.parm1 + "  " + deserializedData.op + "  " + deserializedData.parm2 +
                " = " + result + '\n');
            TextAreaResults.Value = equation.ToString();
        }
    }
```

This worked fine as it was.  But requirements have changed in that the app has to poll data every second.  Therefore I created a wcf web service called by a jquery script to run every second.

The problem is my controls - textbox and textboxarea - generate {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}.  My assumption is that these controls aren't being loaded now that I'm calling the method from JQuery's ajax function (?).

```
$(document).ready(function () {

//while ($('#eThorButton').text != "Stop") {
if ($('#eThorButton').click) {
    $.ajax({
    url: 'Service/eThorService.svc/getUpdate',
    method: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(){
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function (err) {
        alert(err);
    } 
})
//delay(1000);

}
```

});

My controls do show in intellisense and, of course, on Default.aspx when I run it.  How can I fix this?

EDIT

I solved the 'Object not set...' problem by instantiating a new textbox:

```
 public partial class _Default : Page
{
    public static StringBuilder equation = new StringBuilder();
    public TextBox TextBoxTest = new TextBox();
```

When I debug and step through the value is set, the textbox renders but the textbox is empty.  How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Make your method static and add annotation [WebMethod] and return list of results.

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
public static List<string> RenderData(string buttonText)
{
       // return result here
}
```

Pass parameter with data:{buttonText:yourvalue} to $.ajax call. and change the success function and assign values to your control on client side via javascript.

```
success : function(msg){
      if(msg.d!=null){
             $('#<%=TextBoxResult.ClientID%>').val(msg.d[0]);
}
}
```